# add specific named SharedPreferences from resource in PreferenceActivity or PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, preferences

If I have a `Preference-Activity` or `-Fragment` I can provide a preference.xml file to build my `PreferenceScreen` and show it via `addPreferenceFromResource(R.xml.preference)`

Changed values can then be retrieved by `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)`

I'm just wondering if it is possible to take other than the default Preferences for my Fragment.

I want to have a PreferenceFragment that is able to store its Preferences (provided via xml) in Preferences I can retrieve via `context.getSharedPreferences("customPrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` 
but I couldn't find something in the xml like

```
<PreferenceScreen android:prefName="customPrefName">...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to have a custom preference xml file, you need to set preference name before adding it to screen from xml in your PreferenceFragment class.

```
public class CustomNamePreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    private static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "custom_name_xml";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PreferenceManager preferenceManager = getPreferenceManager();
        preferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesName(PREF_FILE_NAME);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        ... //rest of the code
    }
}
```

Note : You need to set shared preference name just after the super call of onCreate() and before calling addPreferencesFromResource() method.

Comment: Thanks, although it smells a bit like a hack, it works well enough to get used